# Simpler way of writing statement with StringBuilder

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I am attempting to convert query below which executes the update statement based on the boolean value. i am adding the warehouse based on an if statement, but i am not quiet sure how to write this with StringBuilder. I am quiet new to C#.

```
string query = value ? "UPDATE  Warehouse SET usen = 'T' WHERE warehouse='01'" : "UPDATE  Warehouse SET use = 'F' WHERE warehouse='01'";
```

I attempted the following:

```
StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();    
query.Append(value ? "UPDATE  Warehouse SET usen = 'T' WHERE warehouse='");
              if (warehouse.Equals("T"))
                query.Append(TWarehouse + "'");
            else if (warehouse.Equals("V"))
                query.Append(VWarehouse + "'");
            query.Append(: "UPDATE  Warehouse SET usen = 'F' WHERE warehouse);
```

This did not work. Clearly I am doing something wrong. Can anyone help me figure this out.

Comment: `query.(TWarehouse + "'");` Is this a typo? it doesn't have the `Append`.

Comment: "Clearly I am doing something wrong" - I think you are talking about constructing SQL queries with string concatenation instead of using parametrized queries... I don't see why constructing query the way you trying to do would produce more readable code.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov They are parameterized based on condition. I can create two separate lines of query based on the Warehouse Condition, but that would be repetitive would it not?

Answer (score 2):

There are better ways than constructing a query in a string and executing it against the database.

As @AlexeiLevenkov suggest, you should use parameterized queries. See [How to  Execute a Parameterized Query](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738521%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Also the `StringBuilder` is recommended for long strings and more complex situations.

From [StringBuilder documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

> "Although the StringBuilder class generally offers better performance
>   than the String class, you should not automatically replace String
>   with StringBuilder whenever you want to manipulate strings.
>   Performance depends on the size of the string, the amount of memory to
>   be allocated for the new string, the system on which your app is
>   executing, and the type of operation. You should be prepared to test
>   your app to determine whether StringBuilder actually offers a
>   significant performance improvement. "

In your case you can use `string.Format` and have a more readable code, like:

```
string format = "UPDATE Warehouse SET use = '{0}' WHERE warehouse='01'";
string query = string.Format(format, value ? "T" : "F");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
query.Append(value ? "UPDATE  Warehouse SET usen = 'T' WHERE warehouse='");
```

This isn't valid C#.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx

I'd recommend reading up on the conditional operator. Look at the first line in your question (I've reformatted it a bit)

```
string query = value 
? "UPDATE  Warehouse SET usen = 'T' WHERE warehouse='01'" 
: "UPDATE  Warehouse SET use = 'F' WHERE warehouse='01'";
```

What this does is conditionally assign a value to the query variable. It'll assign `"UPDATE  Warehouse SET usen = 'T' WHERE warehouse='01'"` if value == true, or it'll assign `"UPDATE  Warehouse SET use = 'F' WHERE warehouse='01'"` if value == false.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you try to do?

```
StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();    
query.Append("UPDATE  Warehouse SET usen = '");
query.Append(value? "T" : "F");
query.Append("' WHERE warehouse='");
if(warehouse.Equals("T"))
{
    query.Append(TWarehouse);
}
else if(warehouse.Equals("V"))
{
    query.Append(VWarehouse);
}
else
{
    query.Append("YourDefaultValue");
}
query.Append("'");
```

As Carlos said, your way of writing the code is wrong.